# Git fetch change from branch A to branch B on local

Tags: git

I struggle a bit doing a thing that I am sure is super easy.

Here is my typical git history:

```
     C--F   <-- [Branch B] The branch I am working on
    /
A--B--D--E  <-- [Branch A] Another branch where work is done
```

`A` is the past and `F` the present.

**Before `push/pull-request` on `Branch B`, I want to be able to `pull` the last change `E` on `Branch A` into my local that is on `Branch B`.**

Ideally, I would like the rebase of `Branch A` in `Branch B` to be a new commit on `Branch B`. So I can easily revert is the two features are not compatible. This commit should only contain the necessary changes for `Branch B` to be up to date with `Branch A`. Thus, in case the two features are not compatible, it is super easy to roll back.

*The changes made on `Branch A` and `Branch B` are not on the same file. If it happens they are, I choose how to manage the conflict (`--rebase`).*

Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks all

---

*[Additional Information]*

I tried to `pull --all` and/or `checkout` on `Branch A`.

However, when I `checkout` back in `Branch B` and `pull` I received the the message `Current branch Branch B is up to date.`

Indeed the base -step `B`- hasn't changed and the last change -step `F`- are already on my local.

However, what I what is to *merge without merging*. I don't want the changes on `Branch B` to go on `Branch A`. I want a step `G` in `Branch B` with the latest change of `Branch A` -step `E`- and the latest change of `Branch B` -step `F`-.

Comment: `git fetch && git merge origin/A` maybe

Comment: If you want a linear history like `A--B--D--E--C--F` you can also try `git fetch && git rebase origin/A`

Comment: Rule for beginners: *Never* use `--all`. Rule for advanced Git users: *Almost never* use `--all`. :-) Seriously, `--all` is passed to `git fetch`, where it means *all remotes*. Unless you have more than one remote, it's not useful. Even then, it's rarely useful.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to have commit "E", you can cherry-pick it:

```sh
git checkout branch-b
git cherry-pick <E commit SHA>
```

Otherwise, if you want to merge all commits, you can rebase/merge branch `branch-a` into branch `branch-b`:

```sh
git checkout branch-b
git fetch && git rebase origin/branch-a
```

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one because it also considers the interpretation of the question that only patch `E` is actually wanted. The original question doesn't say "a change" but it doesn't say "changes" either. This answer could also mention `git rebase origin/branch-a` for completeness but I think it would be worst option to take in reality.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answers (everyone)! I have a question concerning the first option. If I `cherry-pick E`, does this import the changes from `B` to `D` as well as the changes from `D` to `E` ?
If so, I don't understand the difference between the two option. Can you explain it to me please?

Comment: Ideally I would like the rebase of `Branch A` in `Branch B` to be a new commit on `Branch B`. So I can easily revert is the two features are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

As @mousetail mentioned, while on branch B, do `git fetch && git merge origin/A`. Note that merging is **not symmetrical**. As mentioned in the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> Incorporates changes from the named commits (since the time their histories diverged from the current branch) into the current branch.

It only changes the current branch you are on (your branch B in this case) and leaves A as it is. When merge conflicts arise, you can address them locally with additional commits.  When merging is finished you are safe to merge B back into A without conflicts. This is a valid strategy to resolve merge conflicts with a protected branch (for example if A was protected).